# How to get all commit releated to a folder and put it into new repo?

Tags: git, git-history

I have a git repo like

```
repo
/sub-project1
 /sub-folders and files
/sub-project2
 /sub-folders and files
/sub-project3
 /sub-folders and files
```

i want to remove

```
 /sub-project1
     /sub-folders and files
```

and create a new repo with all the git history related to that folder and files need to be also included.

**main consideration is keep only the history related to that folder only and remove all other unwanted history**

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+detach+directory

Comment: @phd thanks for your comment. problem is that im getting all the history of the parent repo. i just need the history related to that sub folder only

Comment: This approach should work. Just make sure, that you type commands properly, and they are executed without errors/warnings.

Comment: @kosist thank for your reply.  tried those. but the issue is all the history trace is coming with the new repo which i dont want. i want only the specific folder's history in the new repo only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep only the history of the desired folder. need to use following command

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <folder-name> -- --all
```